# Live Chatting in a gaming network in windows phone 7

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, xna

Hi guys I am developing a game in which there is requirement for chatting within gamer group. what I mean is I only want the players to chat who have downloaded the game and who are online (using the game). Are there any libraries you may suggest?

Answer (score 1):

Try Openfire http://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/openfire/ (uses XMPP protocol).